# Repeat multiple column elements a variable number of times

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
test <- data.frame(k = 0:5, A = sample(6), B = sample(6), C = sample(6))

k A B C
0 4 5 0
1 2 3 8
2 3 2 2
3 0 0 0
4 1 0 2
```

I’m trying to repeat each element of `A`, `B`, and `C` the number of times specified by `k` and then store new vectors in a new data frame that would look like this:

```
A B C
0 0 1
0 0 1
0 0 1
0 0 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
2 1 1
```

And so on...

Comment: Does my solution work ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with `data.table` package.

```
test <- data.frame(k = 0:5, A = sample(6), B = sample(6), C = sample(6))
library(data.table)
setDT(test)
test[, sapply(.SD, function(x) rep(k, x)), .SDcols = colnames(test)[-1]]
```

Here you perform function `function(x) rep(k, x)`, where `x` is `A:C` (`.SDcols = colnames(test)[-1]`) columns.

Result:

```
      A B C
 [1,] 0 0 0
 [2,] 0 0 0
 [3,] 0 1 1
 [4,] 0 1 1
 [5,] 0 1 1
 [6,] 0 1 1
 [7,] 1 1 1
 [8,] 1 2 1
 [9,] 2 3 2
[10,] 3 3 3
[11,] 3 3 3
[12,] 3 4 3
[13,] 4 4 4
[14,] 4 4 4
[15,] 4 4 4
[16,] 4 4 4
[17,] 5 4 5
[18,] 5 5 5
[19,] 5 5 5
[20,] 5 5 5
[21,] 5 5 5
```

Comment: @Lumimoto you used `sample` function without `seed` I can't reproduce your example.

Comment: @SymbolixAU won't work, this is not wanted OP result as every column (A,B,C) has to repeat different number of times.

Comment: Yep I see that now, I hadn't fully understood the question. Thanks.